# Privilege for longer lasting bounties

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties, privileges

A modest suggestion.

Bounties last a day longer once you reach 8000 rep.

I chose 8000 because 8 is one higher than 7, and there are 7 days in a week. Very scientific.

edit:

So in total; everyone with 8k+ has 8 days for a bounty. It wouldn't stack. Anyone below that has 7 days.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203902/should-we-allow-adding-rep-to-bounties-to-extend-their-duration http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178925/allow-high-reward-bounties-to-be-longer-bounties

Comment: What exactly would this achieve? Why do these users need an extra day? Just because you want to have another privilege in the mix?

Comment: Pretty much. Another small incentive to get people to be involved in SE communities.

Comment: Way too much overhead (in development required for this) for way too little gain, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't downvote, but here's what I think:

It's not quite clear whether you want every additional 1K to add a day to the bounty. If you do, then very high-rep users will be able to place exceptionally long bounties - 365K for one that lasts a *year*. If you don't (i.e. you want any user over 8,000 to have exactly 8-day-long bounties), that seems more like glam than privilege, and not very visible glam. Every existing privilege does something visible (see the 1K avatar mouseover expansion), powerful (see the 500 review queue access), or interesting (see the 10K tools). I don't think anybody except the 8K-er will notice a one-day longer bounty, and if they do, there will probably be confused [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) posts about it.

Back to the "stacking" case: I have a serious concern that such a system would effectively make rep have way more buying power for answers. **Currently, people who are really intent on getting an answer can just place another bounty if one expires with no good answers.** Allowing super high-rep users to put up long bounties with no such recurring price doesn't sit well with me. (But maybe that's just because I'm nowhere close to those numbers.)

Comment: Oh, nah I meant that users with 8k + get an additional day worth of bounty, with the total time being 1 week and 1 day. It wouldn't stack.

Answer (score 2):

This should never be implemented.

Why? Because bounties are used for attracting users to the question with the bounty plus any other reason the poster has decided why the bounty has been made. Of course, if the bounty is extended by 1 more day for "high-privileged" users, it will seem that users care more about the high-rep people rather than the others who daringly sacrificed a chunk of their own rep to create a bounty. No fair for any of us now.

With your comment that this is a small incentive to inspire others to join SE, this will not at all. SE is not to make bounties but is to be a high quality Q&A site. This will not inspire anyone to join except to spam random posts to earn rep and throw away rep as bounties like trash. Very useless to me.

Comment: " this will not at all." It does for me, so obviously it depends on the person. Also, is there an example of a user you know of who gains rep by spamming random posts so he can throw it away on bounties?

Comment: It is a possibility, not a definite result from experience. I hope that the answer is no to everyone.